# Can glibc sprintf be used in a reentrant function?

Tags: c++, c, linux, glibc, reentrancy

Can I use sprintf in a reentrant function if it writes in a local buffer? Something like this:

```
void reentrant_function () { 
    int i = 4;
    char buffer[20];
    snprintf(buffer, 20, "%d", i); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, unless your `buffer` is `static`.

Comment: This answer is possibly right, but it's not obvious. The standard does not require `snprintf` to be reentrant (which is a much stronger requirement than just thread-safe). If glibc makes it reentrant, that's going above the requirements of the standard.

Answer (score 4):

I get to this page because I am also asking the same question. Here is what I read from books:

**Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment: Second Edition**

> Section 10.6
>
> Most functions that are not in Figure 10.4 *(a list of reentrant functions)* are missing because (a) they are known to use static data structures, (b) they call malloc or free, or (c) they are part of the **standard I/O library**.

**The Linux Programming Interface**

> Chapter 21.1.2
>
> Functions can also be nonreentrant if they use static data structures for their
> internal bookkeeping. The most obvious examples of such functions are the members
> of the **stdio library** (printf(), scanf(), and so on), which update internal data
> structures for buffered I/O.

I guess it is implementation depending. It also depends on how do you use snprintf actually (the buffer is essential). The safest answer to the question should be 'no'.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Why do you think you could not? There's no global.

One thing thought: the buffer is local to the function, why would you want to format a string and do nothing with it?

Comment: - I was not sure if the implementation of snprintf was using any static data. Answering your second question: I plan to write the buffer to a socket using send() that I assume is also reentrant (I'll have to take care of errno as well). Am I correct in that assumption?